# cake - Confused about how to count data

Tags: cakephp

I know this question is very simple. But I fail to find it in Google. I'm very new to cake afterall.

For example I have two Model: `Product` and `Category`.

In `Product index` I want to show a list of available Categories and the amount of Products in that category. Like below:

```
Food (10)
Beverages (7)
...
```

I successfully looped the available categories, but not sure how to count it. Below is my loop:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $c): ?>
    <li> ... <?php echo $this->$c->Product->find('count') ?> </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
// The ... part is echo-ing the category name
```

I tried many variations and keep getting error like `ArrayHelper not found` or `ProductHelper not found`

Anyone have the solution?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is my **ProductController** code before I added the `foreach` loop you suggested.

```
public function index() {
            //the first two lines is default from cake bake
        $this->Product->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('products', $this->paginate());
        $categories = $this->Product->Category->find('all');
        $this->set('categories', $categories);
    }
```

Comment: could you show your controller code for getting $categories data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to call `model` in view file, instead you could add the product count to your array from controller itself, like, example code would be:
**in your controller**:

```
$categories = $this->Product->Category->find('all',array('recursive'=>-1));
foreach($categories as $key => $category){
  $categories[$key]['ProductCount'] = $this->Product->find('count',
   array(
     'conditions'=>array('Product.category_id'=>$category['Category']['id'])
   )
  );
}
```

where `ProductCount` can be replaced by name of the product

Comment: Thanks, I will try and I will let you know if success/not

Comment: I got `Call to a member function find() on a non-object` error when using the code `$this->Category...`. Is it because the code is in `ProductController`?

Comment: @DarcCode that was just an example of how you could do it... you need to change it according to your controller, i mean something like $this->Product instead of $this->Category..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calculating the count on each request, use the [counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto) feature to store the products count for each category and then simply display that.

Comment: Hmm I tried the manual but it keeps giving me `undefined index: product_count` error. To use it we just type `$category['Category']['product_count']` right?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to add `product_count` field in my Category table